# select multiple files using glob in python

Tags: python

I have to select all the files in a directory at a time which has y2001, y2002, and y2003 in the mid of filename. How can I?

```
import glob
files = glob.glob('*y2001*.jpg')
```

Comment: http://docs.python.org/2/library/fnmatch.html

Answer (score 2):

You can do it with

```
import glob
files = glob.glob('*y200[123]*.jpg')
```

for futher reference see http://docs.python.org/2/library/glob.html

Comment: thanks btw how to feed them separately y2001, y2002, y2003 . looking for alternative..

Comment: @viena There's no need to feed them separately.

Comment: @ Ashwini Chaudhary please give me alternative like y2001 and y2002 and y2003

Comment: @viena Use a list comprehension on `os.listdir` and filter the list items using either substring match or regex.

Comment: @viena then consider using `fnmatch.fnmatch` in a loop (if you are not satisfied with regex): http://docs.python.org/2/library/fnmatch.html#fnmatch.fnmatch

Answer (score 2):

Here is an overkill method for solving your problem.

```
import os
import re
import functools

def validate_file(validators, file_path):
    return any(re.search(validator, file_path) for validator in validators)

def get_matching_files_in_dir(directory, validator, append_dir=True):
    for file_path in os.listdir(directory):
        if validator(file_path):
            yield os.path.join(directory, file_path) if append_dir else file_path

# define your needs:
matching_patterns = ['y2001', 'y2002', 'y2003']
validator = functools.partial(validate_file, matching_patterns)

# usage
list(get_matching_files_in_dir('YOUR DIR', validator))
```

An Example:

```
>>> matching_patterns = ['README']
>>> validator = functools.partial(validate_file, matching_patterns)
>>> print list(get_matching_files_in_dir('C:\\python27', validator))
['C:\\python27\\README.txt']
```